# Displaying the correct size in Windows' Add/Remove Programs

Tags: windows-installer

I have a need to manually setup the registry settings for an entry in Window's Add/Remove Programs (for XP and Vista).  Everything works except for the displayed size.

According to [this 2004 post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/09/178342.aspx) by Raymond Chen it should be possible by setting the `EstimatedSize` registry value but it doesn't work.  [This more recent MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105(VS.85).aspx) says the `EstimatedSize` value is "*Determined and set by the Windows Installer.*"  Does anyhow know how I can manually set the size value outside the Windows Installer?

(Suggestions to use a single large MSI are appreciated but we have done that in the past and its proven difficult and inflexible. Our current approach is a custom application to manage hundreds of smaller MSI packages, but this means the application itself has to write out the registry settings for Add/Remove Programs.)

Answer (score 0):

you could try building the sub-projects into msm (merge modules) and then linking the lot into a single msi - you get the benefits of having individual modules, and a single msi that way.

Comment: Yeah that would work in theory and we have done it that way in the past, but we have such a large volume of data it quickly becomes a maintenance nightmare. 35GB and 200,000 files shipped monthly to thousands of users.